# Android Phonegap hide soft keyboard when next button is pressed

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

For the life of me I can't seem to figure this out but when you use a  in the application, it shows the numeric keyboard.

The soft keyboard will appear but when you hit the Next key it does nothing. I can make the keyboard show and hide but I can't get an event listener to pickup the Next Key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I would comment, but I don't have enough points.

This appears to be a bug in Chrome/Native Android browser. See [Android Soft keyboard: Next button not "tabbing" between HTML5 number inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011159/android-soft-keyboard-next-button-not-tabbing-between-html5-number-inputs)

I'm not sure if it is possible to detect the Next button press in Phonegap. Would be interested to know..