# Android Soft keyboard: Next button not "tabbing" between HTML5 number inputs

Tags: html, android-softkeyboard

I was testing out the HTML5 input type "number" with my Android phone. Whilst doing this I noticed that when the soft keyboard is active on a number input type the next button doesn't appear to tab between inputs.

Now I assume it *should* tab between inputs but I can't find any definite wording that says this *is* the case.

I am currently using Android 4.1.1 with the stock browser. I have also tried in Chrome with the same results.

I have a sample page here : http://jsfiddle.net/axECg/ and here is the code for it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            Number 1<input type="number" id="numA" name="numA" /><br />
            Number 2<input type="number" id="numB" name="numB" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or just expecting a bit too much in regards to HTML5 + Android at the moment?

Thanks

Comment: I uploaded your html to my play site : http://www.appmalt.info/mytest.html I accessed it through my android phone and the "Next" button seems to be working fine. It tabs between the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go, I tried on your site with the same results. I suspect it's now back to the version of Android and/or the mobile browser I'm using. Which version of OS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

This does appear to be a limitation of Chrome/Android browser. An [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142233) has been logged. I've tested the example (and tried some modifications) on two devices with multiple browsers.

Nexus 7 4.2.1 and Samsung S3 4.1.1

- Chrome: 'Next' button shows but does not function
- FF Mobile: Works as
  expected

I've also tested input types: `email`, `text`, `tel`. In Chrome they either show a non-functional 'Next' button or no 'Next' button. FF Mobile has a working 'Next' button for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I note that there are two "next" buttons on my Android Keyboard; there's one above the keypad that seems to properly tab fields with it's sibling [Prev] button; The [Next] on the keypad does not seem to send an event.